# Questions regarding Behavior of TransactionScope for Database in .NET

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, transactionscope, msdtc, data-cleaning

I am using TransactionScope for executing a test method. **I want that all the changes done to the database during the execution of test method gets rolled back to previous state in the end.**

**For achieving this I am not writing scope.Complete() at the end of Scope.**

My Question :

Do the changes done to database by `dbContext.Savechanges()` gets reverted when I do not write  `transaction.Complete();` in the end ?

Comment: You could simply try. It does.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the approach taken right?

Using EF you could just not use a Tx scope and just not save the changes. Depends what you are testing - you may not find model errors without writing the the database.

> Do I need to add dbContext.SaveChanges();

Depends whether you want this to happen or not.

> Is it necessary to write changes to database so that data can be used by other 
>   routines?

With all respect, what are you asking US? You should know what you want. For unit testing normally it is not the case - but for integration tests it may well be. You must know. I am always astonished when people here show up and ask for advice ignoring the fact that I may as well roll a dice without them providing any information. Hey, tell me the route from my place to the office of the company I want to visit. I will neither tell you where I live nor where I want to go, but please tell me how to drive there. Get it?

> I am using two different database in test method. I am able to access
>   the one AviTrackEntities but not the other ImportDataEntities.

Then your code is faulty, or your configuration. You ever learned how to make a bug report? It involves analysis, and posting THE ERROR. How are we supposed to know without any information?

> Is there any flaw in the code or something I am missing ?

What you totally miss is that we have no access to the source, the machines and your brain. We can not make a basic bug report for you. Given the information - FIX IT. Yes, something is wrong. What - no clue. You prefer to not help us helping you.

Database unit tests are notoriously complicated due to the persistent nature of databases. Resetting the database to a known start state can be complex.